# Botão desalinha depois de trocar css com Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Tenho o seguinte input:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no botão alterar um novo input aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar nesse botão remover, o primeiro input volta a aparecer, só que o botão quebra a linha e fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis o script por trás:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){      
        $("#edita,#remove").click(function(){

      var id = $(this).attr('id');

      if(id=='edita'){
        $('#numero').css("display","none");
        $('#edita').css("display","none");
        $('#trocaNum').css("display","block");
      }
      if(id=='remove'){
        $('#numero').css("display","block");
        $('#edita').css("display","inline");
        $('#trocaNum').css("display","none"); 
      }

    });        
  });
</script>
```

Sugestões ?

Comment: Pode postar o HTML?

Comment: Troca o $('#numero').css("display","block"); por $('#numero').css("display","");

Comment: @RBoschini deu certo. Se quiser responder pra eu marcar como resolvida. Alias esse script está bom? ou tenho como fazer algo mais otimizado.

Comment: @Bia já postei, obrigado pela gentileza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troca o

```
$('#numero').css("display","block");
```

por

```
$('#numero').css("display","");
```

Assim deve resolver.